# ARIA accessibility issues with <Select>

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, axe

### Background

We are using `@axe-core/react` to work on ARIA accessibility in react application. By default, on page reload no issues are reported, but on `Select` click we are facing various issues with accessibility, according to axe-core/react.

### Problems

> serious: Page must have means to bypass repeated blocks
> https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.0/bypass?application=axeAPI

> moderate: Document must have one main landmark
> https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.0/landmark-one-main?application=axeAPI

> moderate: All page content must be contained by landmarks
> https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.0/region?application=axeAPI

In addition to problems, there are 2 more:

> moderate: Page must contain a level-one heading https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.0/page-has-heading-one?application=axeAPI

> serious: Elements must have sufficient color contrast https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.0/color-contrast?application=axeAPI

### Code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axe from "@axe-core/react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuItem, Select, InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";

const BypassRepeatedBlocks = () => (
  <div aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="#select-content" style={{ display: "none" }}>
      bypass repeated blocks
    </a>
  </div>
);
const NavigationSample = () => (
  // we must have <nav> here in order to put content inside landmark. Otherwise we would get issue.
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

const HomePage = () => <div></div>;

const App = () => (
  // BrowserRouter, Route and <Link> (NavigationSample) are the cause of bypass repeated blocks issue
  <BrowserRouter>
    {/**but with BypassRepeatedBlocks portion of code, it can be solved  */}
    <BypassRepeatedBlocks />
    <NavigationSample />

    <main>
      <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
      {/**without <h1> there is heading issue on page loading */}
      <h1>H1</h1>

      <InputLabel id="my-input" style={{ color: "black" }}>
        Sort
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        id="select-content"
        labelId="my-input"
        value="item1"
        style={{ width: "200px" }}
      >
        <MenuItem key="item1" value="item1">
          item1
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem key="item2" value="item2">
          item2
        </MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </main>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
axe(React, ReactDOM, 1000);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

### Observations

- As with shown code, when drop-down menu is shown I can navigate through menuitems (options) with key down and key up from keyboard, and that is what is important, from accessibility point of view, right?
- After clicking on Select and inspecting HTML elements of web page, I can see two things: first, that my main content gets hidden `<div id="root" aria-hidden="true">`, and second that new `<div>` is generated with `role='presentation`' which contains this drop-down content. And it is outside of `<main>` which sort of explains the issue `All page content must be contained by landmarks`, as well as `Document must have one main landmark` and `Page must contain a level-one heading`
- In addition to previous observation, I tried to add `MenuProps={{ disablePortal: true }}` to Select element, and issue `All page content must be contained by landmarks` was removed but i don't know if and what negative impacts this can have
- from what i read on internet on this topic, I find this case (select, drop-down) to be very specific and advance.

### Questions

1. Is there a proper way to handle mentioned issues for `Select` element? How?
2. Is this one of the situations to be considered as a trade-off (*don't have to / can't* get rid of all issues)?
3. If 2. is true, is then that bug to axe-core/react tool?

Let me know if I can provide more details, or update some content.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Github repo for reproduction: https://github.com/StefanZivkovic/aria-accessibility-problems.
When you `git clone` it from cmd, navigate to `cd aria-accessibility-problems`, execute `npm i`, then`npm start` and wait for server to start. If you use VS code, from cmd do `code .` to open the files and check the code if you want.

By the way, i found how to overcome `Page must have means to bypass repeated blocks`, at least on this simple example. That particular issue was caused by `react-router-dom`, and its elements, `Link`, `BrowserRouter` and `Route`. Might be useful for some.

Comment: We would need to see a working fiddle, my guess is your select is not actually a native select and when it renders in it is causing all of the accessibility issues mentioned. Before someone interacts with it I am guessing there is no inner HTML which is why you don't get the bypass blocks warning etc. Colour contrast is just that, my guess is you don't have enough contrast on open items etc. Could you either provide a URL to a publicly available version of the page or produce a working fiddle that replicates the problem as at the moment it is pure conjecture.

Comment: i have issues adding dependencies like material-ui and @axe-core/react in fiddle. I think i will make new github repo for it.

Comment: let me know if you have problems cloning the repo: https://github.com/StefanZivkovic/aria-accessibility-problems